# Programmaitcally making a VOIP call with Zoiper on an android tablet

Tags: android, android-intent, sip, voip

I'm writing a simple Android app that has a button that makes a SIP call to a pre specified number. I'm using an Android tablet, version 4.0.4. I have set the button handler to do as follows:

```
Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOpenDoor);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
              }
        });
```

I expected that to bring up a "Which application would you like to use to dial this number" pop up (I have both Zoiper and CSipSimple installed). But instead it just pops up a dialog asking me if I would like to add this number to my contacts. I feel like this is because I'm using a tablet and not a phone. I've tried changing the Uri to `sip:123456789` and `zoiper:123456789`. I've also tried setting the intent's package like so:

```
callIntent.setPackage("com.zoiper.android.app");
```

All to no avail. My permissions are as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I should say, I'm not limited to using Zoiper. Any SIP app should do. But I've definitely seem the "please choose which app to complete this action with" dialog pop up on phones when trying to dial a phone number from outside the dialer, with zoiper, skype and the actual dialer as well as anything else that supports dialling.

Comment: Aaltan> Did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, inspired by @user2999943's answer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel://" + 123456789));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue with Zoiper application. The solution which worked for me was to pass HTML string to TextView. Now, when I am clicking that TextView, I get a dialog "Complete action using..." with Zoiper application populated in the list.

In your layout add TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="98dp"        
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="No phone number"        
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorLink="#000000"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

In your activity:

```
TextView numberField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberField);
numberField.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


String htmlText = "<a href=tel:555>555</a>";                

Spannable s = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
for (URLSpan u: s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class)) 
{
    s.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan() 
    {
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) 
        {
             tp.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }, s.getSpanStart(u), s.getSpanEnd(u), 0);
}
numberField.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what about zoiper but this code works to call with CSIPSimple:

```
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setPackage("com.csipsimple");
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sip:123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```